# Search query api to get birthday date

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-rest-api, people-search

I am trying to use the sharepoint REST api to get all users birthdays.

So I am using a crawled property **People:SPS-Birthday** with the managed property **RefinableDate00**.

Yesterday 15/08/2019 (Thursday) it was working fine, but today when I search the users using the query:

```
_api/search/query?querytext=*&selectproperties='PreferredName,PictureURL,AccountName,RefinableDate00'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'
```

The `RefinableDate00` is empty.

I dont know why this happening, someone faced this kind of thing before?

Comment: Is RefinableDate00 managed property still bound to People:SPS-Birthday?

Comment: yes. it is bound to People:SPS-Birthday

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that either somebody has modified the search resultat source you are using or the mapping has changed or you are using another context. What does the SP Search Query tool shows for that query?

Comment: I tested with the SP Search Query Tool and the property "refinabledate00" is empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Below are the possible situations happened in the back-end,

1. Particular user's Birthday was modified in the user profile.
2. Mapping of the Search Crawl proeprty "RefinableDate00" with User Profile managed property "SPS-Birthday" is modfied.
3. User's profile sync happened with Active Directory, and Active Directory may be update the empty value!

Please checkout the user's UserProfileProperties is still returns the value for Birthdate.

/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v=

If the UserProfile property didn't have the Birthdate, update the value in Birthdate and wait for crawl to appear in search results.

Comment: 1. This user has a birthdate set up in delve page
2. The Crawl proeprty "RefinableDate00" is bound with User Profile managed property "SPS-Birthday"
3. I dont know, i am in Sharepoint Online

I checkout the  UserProfileProperties and it has a value for birthday 

<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>SPS-Birthday</d:Key>
<d:Value>16/08/2000 00:00:00</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>